# Muti-module Springboot project active profile not success

Tags: spring-boot, profile, multi-module

I have a multi-modules springboot project with structure like this:

```
|--multiDemo
|--admin (with profiles application.yml and application-dev.yml)
|--infrastructure (with profile application-basic.yml)
```

I try this in application.yml to active different profiles:

```
spring:
  profiles:
      active: basic
```

When i active "dev", it works well. But when i active "basic", it doesn't work thought the terminal displays
The following 1 profile is active: "basic"
Why this would happen and how should i acitve profiles in different modules correctly?

Comment: please take: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module (15 minutes) ,  then "overfly" https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles (in depth: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/environment.html#beans-definition-profiles) ..then please precise your question ([edit])